# is someone allowed to post an image of me on social media without my consent?

Tags: copyright, consent

i have an old friend who has been posting pictures of me without my permission. i’ve asked her to delete them but she just keeps refusing. can i take legal action? or is it possible for me to get them deleted somehow? i would not like to be associated with her.